# A verb that means “to prove someone is guilty of a crime”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, legalese

**Preface**: I don't think there is a single-word (verb) that expresses the concept I am asking for, in which case I'd settle for the least ambiguous and most common phrase or idiom that describes the following situation.

**Context**
I was reading a short story from a private student of mine when I came across this line:

> Lucy realized she had the proof **to frame** Robert [for the murders].

To [frame](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/frame) someone is to arrange or plant evidence in such a way that an innocent person appears to be guilty in the eyes of the law. My student's sentence would be fine if Robert were innocent of the crime, or if there was no evidence that linked Robert to the murders but somehow Lucy managed to plant false evidence which resulted in his arrest.

But in my student's story, Robert isn't innocent. He did commit the two murders and the evidence Lucy found was not planted, nor false, but led to the police arresting him for the two murders.

I suggested the following solutions:

1. *Lucy realized she found the proof that **[nailed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/nail)** Robert for the murders*
2. *Lucy realized she found the proof **to incriminate** Robert.*
3. *Lucy realized she found the evidence which **proved** Robert's guilt.*
4. *Lucy found **the smoking gun** that proved Robert's guilt.*

Sentences 1 and 2 are fine within the plot of the story but taken out of context,   they could still suggest Robert was set up by Lucy, i.e. he was innocent. Sentences 3 and 4 are, I think, the least ambiguous. My student liked the expression “[smoking gun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/smoking-gun?q=smoking%20gun)” but added:

> A *smoking gun* is not a verb, I still have to say Lucy *found* the smoking gun which *incriminated* Robert.

---

**Questions**

If “to frame” someone is *to plant evidence that ‘proves’ an innocent person is guilty*, is there a verb that means: *to find evidence that unequivocally  proves a person is guilty*?
Perhaps there is an obscure legal term hidden in OED, or maybe an obsolete expression, which escapes me. Here is my student's sentence with the blank space.

> Lucy realized she had the proof to _________ Robert

But I am open to other suggestions and solutions so long as its clear that the evidence shows us that Robert is guilty.

Am I right to ascertain sentences 1 and 2 are possibly ambiguous? And finally, are there other alternatives to the ones I suggested?

Comment: So you're looking for an antonym to *exonerate*.

Comment: Not sure if ***convict*** may apply  here: 
*When you convict  someone of a crime, you find them guilty.

Comment: The opposite of *exculpate* is *inculpate*.

Comment: Yes, @PeterShor. precisely.The verb I'm looking for, if it exists, is a sort of verb equivalent of *smoking gun*.

Comment: @Josh61 *"Lucy realized she found the evidence to convict Robert"*, also works but does not substitute "find evidence which condemns a guilty person" Or maybe it does??

Comment: If *inculpate* is too Latinate for you, the OED also has *guilt* as an obsolete verb, with a 1553 citation of “Hath he then guilted himself of murder?”

Comment: @tchrist but how would you fit *inculpate* in the sentence? My private student studies Latin at school, and *incolpare* is Italian, so no problems there.

Comment: ***Sentence*** :
To impose a sentence on (a criminal defendant found guilty, for example).
Lucy found evidence to sentence him to jail.

Comment: OED: 1. trans. To bring a charge against; to accuse; to blame, find fault with. 1846 De Quincey Glance Wks. Mackintosh Wks. XIII. 65 ― The poor lady could have had no rational motive for inculpating herself. 2. To involve in a charge; to incriminate. 1897 Mary Kingsley W. Africa 427 ― Attempting to exculpate himself and inculpate Dr. Nassau for not having told him one was necessary. Hence inculpated, inculpating ppl. adjs. 1892 Pall Mall G. 15 Mar. 2/3, ― I think it is generally felt that the inculpating lie is more serious than the exculpating falsehood.

Comment: Just as a side note, *incastrare* does not necessarily refer to someone who is innocent:  *incastrare il colpevole, metterlo alle strette con prove schiaccianti*. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/incastrare.shtml

Comment: @Josh61 Turns out he was thinking of incastrare ("frame" / "incriminate") but it's still wrong, if the person being framed is not innocent, but I now realize that in Italian, *incastrare* also works if the party is guilty. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incastrare/ It can either be *frame*; *incriminate* or "nail". Più uno per l'italia!

Comment: @Josh61 Sentencing comes after guilt determination; it's not the same thing. The legal term is **convict**.

Comment: @TylerH - I  know, the idea is that the evidence found is so strong that it is like  a sentence to jail.

Comment: @Josh61 Sentencing would be a great word to *imply* someone has been proven guilty, but not a great word to *mean* someone has been proven guilty.

Comment: Although it's an adjective, the word [*culpable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culpable) is entirely missing from this page. Evidence that finds you culpable would be proof that you're "guilty of doing something wrong".

Comment: If Lucy’s realization occurred AFTER hearing that Robert was found guilty (& she was rejoicing/lamenting the fact that her find had caused/insured his conviction), then “which proved” would work. But if her realization occurred BEFORE his having been found guilty/having admitted his guilt, then “which WOULD prove” (or some qualifier, e.g., “which proved to her satisfaction/in the eyes of God”, etc) would be required. Not even poetic license can diminish the importance of a murder trial in a discussion of proving someone guilty of murder.  (But “nailed” would be perfect for proving infidelity!)

Comment: @PapaPoule - With that reasoning, I implore you to upvote [TimLymington's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269306/a-verb-that-means-to-prove-someone-is-guilty-of-a-crime/269346#269346).

Comment: Would _expose_ do in the context? Lucy realized she had the proof to **expose** Robert. In the sense of revealing his guilt.

Comment: I am curious to know what expression you will chose in the end :)

Comment: @Josh61 I'm curious too, I had no idea the question would attract so many answers. I thought my four solutions were pretty extensive.

Comment: if you have enough to get attentions on them, it's "implicate" if  you have enough to get them arrested it's "Collar" , or "get a collar on" them, if enough to prove it in court, it's "convict"

Comment: I fail to see why "... to convict ..." is not the trivially correct response. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens *convict* has been suggested several times. I hope you upvoted those answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Only the (to my mind) best one, which made clear agreement with me on there really being no suitable alternative for the meaning desired by OP..

Comment: I cannot choose, there are three answers (only one in the top three) which I am dithering between.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. Two puzzles stand out: (1) is the change from "Lucy realized she had ...." to "Lucy realized she found ...." material to the question? and (2) in the comments, you suggest that substituting or being able to substitute 'to condemn' is necessary--doesn't that substitution in itself answer your question: "Lucy realized she had proof to [or, 'that would'] condemn Robert [for the murders]."?

Comment: @JEL  (1) it's not *that* important: "She found the proof" tells us explicitly *who* discovered it. "She had the proof" insinuates that she was the discoverer. (2) One comment, with two ?? added on, suggests I wasn't sure. I had *NO* idea this post would attract so many answers, and quite a few duplicates. One thing I know for sure, I bet Josh61 is kicking himself for not posting "convict" first as an answer! :) Perhaps my comment perplexed/dissuaded him.

Comment: Anyway, I upvoted the answer I considered best. The answer listing *condemn* might be better if fleshed out a bit. Nonetheless, your student might be better served by explanations of legalities than by rewriting the sentence: for example, the standard of **proof** would be, in our and some other legal systems, "beyond a reasonable doubt". Lucy's proof, in short, would not be legal proof; legal proof is decided by a jury's reasonable doubt. Further, police do not arrest people on the basis of proof, but on a preponderance of evidence. Don't know if that helps....

Comment: @JEL There's only one post that suggests *condemn* casually. I think the whole thing has been taken far too seriously. The line is expressing Lucy's realization: 1) who is the murderer 2) he can be arrested, it's only *later* that he can be put on trial. This isn't a Chrichton, Grisham or Larsson novel! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Can you explain what you mean by " is kicking himself for not posting "convict" first as an answer!"  Why?

Comment: I wonder if, at the outer limits, "condemn" would be usable for this purpose.  "Indict" is also useful in some more figurative cases (i.e. 'the results were an indictment of his policies.')

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You already have the most common phrase: *the evidence to prove [* or *that would prove] Robert guilty*.

If the word *proof* is important, simply *the proof that Robert was guilty* would work well.

Comment: Simple, elegant, and authoritative solution to the problem, I think.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. All the other words can be used whether someone is actually guilty or not; **proof** is the word which means he is definitively guilty. Combine **proof** with any of the other words, and it still means he is guilty. (NB: Not with "frame" though, as "frame" definitively means he is not guilty and so would be a contradiction).

Comment: I don't see why examples 3 and 4 aren't already complete answers to the question. Let __proof__ stand alone and it's the most authoritative. I think it's adding the different qualifiers that is creating the ambiguity. "Proof of guilt" leaves the least wiggle room. "Smoking gun" can still be used in the sentence,  but proof is the operative word. So agreeing with Tim on the second sentence above. Not "the evidence *to* prove [or that *would* prove] Robert guilty," but simply *the proof* [of Robert's guilt].

Comment: Just showed my student all the answers, and he prefers this one. End of discussion.

Answer (score 47):

According to Merriam-Webster:

> [**implicate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicate): (3a) to bring into intimate or incriminating connection
>   *evidence that implicates him in the bombing*

So I would write this:

> Lucy realized she found the proof that **implicated** Robert in the murders.

You can omit "in the murders" if it is implied by context.

Comment: Also, you might say "Lucy found _the proof that implicated_ Robert in the murders." This phrasing indicates that the evidence itself connects him to the crime, without any tampering on her part.

Comment: Objection, circumstantial. *Correlation is not causation*.

Comment: I don't like this one, though the dictionary definitions do tend to suggest that it's ok. To my ear: to **implicate** is to **imply**, i.e. to **suggest** but *not* to **prove**. I believe that you could frame someone by implicating them. I much prefer the OP's word of **incriminate**. But then maybe you could frame someone by incriminating them too... I'm getting myself more and more confused!

Comment: @AndyT: To my ear, incriminating happens when you commit the crime.

Comment: @Kevin - I've only just checked out [incriminate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incriminating?s=t)'s definition. It is, apparently, 1. "to accuse of or present proof of a crime or fault" or 2. to "cause to be or appear to be guilty". So your meaning matches with 2a, whereas I'm looking at 1b. But the words "accuse" and "appear to be" both allow for actual non-guilt. Hence I no longer think **incriminate** is better than **implicate**.

Comment: still not a perfect antonym of *exonerate*, which is what I think is sought here, but of all that I can find and all that I read here, I think it's the best for a single verb

Answer (score 21):

**[Convict](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convict)** is the correct word here. It's the strongest and most succinct, though legally speaking, Lucy would not do the convicting: that would be filled by the role of judge, jury, or relevant prosecuting attorney for the government.

*Indict* and *implicate* are too weak: especially in modern, western legal systems, the accused benefits from the presumption of innocence. If you have enough evidence to *implicate* someone, that might mean you have a strong hunch based on a rumor you heard. If you have enough evidence to *indict* someone, well, now you've got a thumbprint, a motive, and maybe some supporting evidence ... but generally you don't need *proof* for that.  If the evidence is strong enough, then the proof may be sufficient to *convict*.

Note, the word *convict* has at least 3 meanings: The word above is a verb, with the emphasis on the last syllable, the "vict". When the emphasis is on the first syllable, "con", it refers to a person who has been convicted of a crime and has not yet finished service their punishment. An "ex-convict" is someone who has served their punishment. Finally, the verb is turned into an adjective via its past participle where one usage takes on a slightly different meaning: "John felt convicted" means (in a way) that "John felt certain and resolute", but possibly with a feeling of guilt and remorse; presumably, this sense of the word comes from the idea that John's conscience convicted John as if he had done a crime; his *conviction* is now a determination to set thing straight.

Comment: **convict**: *trans.* To prove (a person) guilty of an offence which makes him liable to legal punishment; spec. to find or declare guilty, after trial before a legal tribunal, by the verdict of a jury or the decision of a judge. *[OED]*

Comment: I had to place *convict* in bold and add a link because it's tiring to see people posting duplicate answers. I am also fully aware you weren't the first to suggest *convict*, but your post seems to support *convict* more strongly than others.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, thanks.  jxh's answer is good too.

Answer (score 18):

> > Lucy realized she finally had enough evidence **to indict** Robert on the charge of murder.

**Indict** in·dict /inˈdīt/ verb, North American –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=iondite&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=indicted)
past tense: indicted; past participle: indicted

> formally accuse of or charge with a serious crime.

Because of *double jeopardy*, one had best be sure you have all your ducks in a row before you indict a suspect. Prosecutors may spend years collecting evidence before they are willing to bring up charges.

Due to the maximum length of time one can be held without charges, suspects of crimes committed (other than those where they're **caught red handed**), are not placed under arrest until a case is built against them. E.g., Drew Peterson.

You only indict someone once (you think, and the DA agrees that) you have enough ["evidence that ‘proves’ them guilty"] beyond reasonable doubt. This evidence must also include a means of **probable cause** for said [indictment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indictment).

---

However, *to find evidence that unequivocally proves a person is guilty*, is most likely to be done during [discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_%28law%29) (assuming the detective's findings were unsubstantial).

> Under the law of the United States, civil discovery is wide-ranging and can involve any material which is "reasonably calculated to lead to admissible evidence." –Wiki

---

> > Not even half way through discovery, Lucy realized she already had enough evidence to also indict Robert on the charge of murder.

In the US, **all suspects are innocent until proven guilty in a court of law**. The colloquial saying you're looking for is *'a smoking gun'*, however legally the concept does not exist and therefore any word you find is inadmissible.

---

See also, **dead-bang**. –[definitions.uslegal.com](http://definitions.uslegal.com/d/dead-bang-winner/)

> A dead-bang winner is defined as “an issue which was obvious from the trial record and would have resulted in a reversal on appeal.” James v. McKee, 2009 U.S. Dist. LEXIS 102380 ( E.D. Mich. Nov. 3, 2009)

*Take your shot Funboy. You got me dead-bang.* –*The Crow*

> > And with this new evidence, Lucy realized she had Robert dead-bang.

See also, [**Dead to Rights**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127428/origin-of-the-expression-dead-to-rights) –SE

> > Lucy realized she had proof Robert was the murderer, dead to rights.

---

IMO, *found* is the most important word in that sentence. I can only surmise that the reasons *'uncovered evidence', 'newly found evidence', ect.* are so cliche, is that your word doesn't exist (and if it does, it has no legal bearing).

Comment: +1 for the interesting and new terms. Your first sentence seems to imply that Lucy already had some evidence,  but until the discovery  there was nothing that indicated Robert was the killer, only suspicions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - That's the reason I included *also* in the second example. Take for example an aggravated robbery. They might charge them with the robbery, but hold off on the assault charge, and use the first indictment as a means to acquire enough evidence to *hopefully* lead to a conviction on that, also. It's easy to get a search warrant for a suspected robber's house, probable cause may be much harder to get on a murder suspect's. My advice: never do two illegal things at the same time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm a stickler for titles: *Evidence that supports the argument that someone is guilty* implicates them. Implication does not prove someone is guilty of a crime. That is the word *you're* looking for, but it's not what the title is asking for. Upon reflection, I'm going to have to upvote Tim's answer, which includes *would prove*.

Comment: Good explanation. +1

Comment: @Mazura I think the title is fine as I see it right now - Mari-LouA is looking for such a verb (which would be an antonym for exonerate). However, such a word does not, as far as anyone on this discussion has indicated, currently exist in the English Language. I would say *implicate* is closer than *indict* to being an antonym for exonerate. Though *indict* captures some of the formality that *implicate* does not, *implicate* implies **actual** connection to the events, where *indict* is essentially just a claim of guilt.

Comment: *Prove* is nearly perfect, but is "part of the definition" sought, and is thus missing part of the meaning for the word sought. That meaning has to be provided by additional words, such as *guilt* or *committed*. To *exonerate* is to 'prove someone not guilty', but it does not have an antonym that means to 'prove someone guilty' - we've gotta figure out what is the closest, unless we wanna pull a Shakespeare and try out "unexonerate" (?)

Comment: I'm going to upvote this for "Dead To Rights" because I would consider editing the phrase to describe the evidence as "decisive" rather than just using a word or phrase to implicate Robert.
Something like "Lucy had the decisive evidence she needed to get Robert dead to rights." or something like that.

Answer (score 17):

I agree that the verb *convict* pretty much means *found someone is guilty of a crime*. The *proving* part is the prosecution process itself.

If you are looking for a more direct way to apply the *proof* in your sample sentence, I would use ***committed***:

> Lucy realized she had proof that Robert *committed* the murders.

Comment: Yes, *committed*. This preserves the sense of the student's original sentence **as explicated** by the OP. I note that framing (e.g., contriving false evidence to aid in convicting) a *guilty* party is a commonplace. I also note, on another tack, that in some legal systems (e.g., Canadian) convicting and finding quilty are distinct phases. Of the others: *to indict* is formal, and typically can only be done by constituted authority; *to implicate* does not necessarily imply guilt, as others have pointed out; *to convict* would work, but only with a lot of added flab or phrasal imprecision.

Comment: Which term would you prefer between *proof* and *evidence* and why?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *Evidence* in of itself is rarely conclusive. It is usually some fact out of a collection of facts that can be used to build a case. So you could say *I have evidence that proves he committed ...*, but if you just say *I have evidence that he committed ...* sounds much weaker, because the evidence could be circumstantial.

Comment: +1 @JEL  for clearly and correctly noting that “framing a guilty party” can and does occur.  According to  “[The Skeptical Juror](http://www.skepticaljuror.com/2014/04/framing-guilty-framing-innocent.html)”: “… the classic frame up [of an innocent party] is more fiction than reality. In the real world, nearly all the framing is done by the State.”

Comment: I just want to add even if there is conclusive and uncontested *proof* that a person *committed* murder, that person may still be found *not guilty* for other reasons, perhaps due to extenuating circumstances or due to legal technicality or due to whatever reason a lawyer may be able to conjure up.

Comment: Thanks, @PapaPoule. A great lot of esthetic pleasure in reading mystery-suspense-detective fiction results from the moral and ethical quandary associated with a framing-the-guilty trope. More remarkable, perhaps, although I'd not space in the comment to tease it out, is that in Canada (et al.) you can be found guilty but not convicted: sufficient evidence to establish *actus reus* and *mens rea* results in a finding of guilt; however, the next phase allows raising several sorts of active defense which may, if successful, foreclose on conviction.

Comment: I rather liked this answer, but because the question was inspired by a student of mine, I thought he should decide which answer he preferred. Sorry about taking away the 15 points, but blame it on the kid, not on me! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No worries! You can always award me a bounty :-)

Answer (score 11):

I am tempted to propose the following:

> Lucy realized she had the proof to **establish** Robert's **guilt**.

Per Merriam-Webster:

> [establish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/establish) *verb*
>
> : to cause (someone or something) to be widely known and accepted
>
> : to put (someone or something) in a position, role, etc., that will
> last for a long time
>
> : to begin or create (something that is meant to last for a long time)

Answer (score 7):

Sentence 1 (with *nail*) sounds a bit colloquial to my non-native ears. Furthermore, I think that “nailed Robert to the murders” links Robert to the murders but is ambiguous as to whether he was the murderer, an accomplice, or perhaps even merely involved in some way (e.g. he drove the murderer to the place where the crime took place but did not know of the murderer's intent beforehand). “Nailed Robert *for* the murders” would be a lot closer to the intended meaning.

Sentence 2 is definitely ambiguous: *incriminate* can mean merely that there is enough evidence of involvement to warrant an inquiry and perhaps a trial, not proof of guilt.

With *frame*, there's an emphasis on spreading the false information regarding the party being guilty. A word that applies when the guilt is genuine and emphasizes the public knowledge of that guilt is *expose*.

> Lucy realized she had the proof to expose Robert for committing the murders.

What I find a little awkward is that *expose* doesn't work well without adding the word *committing*: “expose Robert for the murders” doesn't sound right. Depending on the context, this might work:

> Lucy realized she had the proof to expose Robert as the murderer.

Comment: "for being" -> "as"

Comment: One doesn't nail Robert **to** the murders, one nails him **for** the murders. One could also pin the murders **on** him.

Comment: @Vérace thank you for pointing out my mistake, I hadn't realized that I used the wrong preposition. Indeed, you nail someone **to** the wall  or **to** a cross but you are nail someone **for** a crime.

Comment: @Mari-LouA both prepositions seem fine to me but mean different things. To "nail someone **for** the murders" would be to punish them. To "nail someone **to** the murders" is much less common, but perfectly understandable, meaning to unequivocably link them to the murders. As i say, it's not common, borderline neologism, but understandable.

Comment: @steveverrill - it may be "understandable", but this is "language and usage" - and "nail to" in this context strikes me (as a speaker of English from birth) as incongruous. You may disagree, but there I stand and I am unanimous in that :-)  "Pin" the murders on somebody could either be a justifiable attribution of guilt or a frame job IMHO.

Comment: @Verace My point is, to me as a native speaker they mean different things. "Nail somebody for a crime" means to arrest or punish them. "Nail somebody to a crime" is incongrous, but clearly means to establish a link between them and the crime. To me "pin on" means an injust attribution of guilt, either by the perpetrator covering their tracks, but normally by incompetent or corrupt authorities, as per the last quote on this page http://www.filmsite.org/shaw2.html.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In my opinion you should roll back your edit on the question.

Comment: @steveverrill Substituting *Robert* with *him*, I only found one instance on the net where the writer/author/blogger used the phrase in the same way as you interpreted my sentence i.e. *meaning to unequivocally link someone to the murders.* (However, I'm seriously considering whether I should ask a new question!)

Answer (score 4):

Edited.

I would suggest "Lucy realized she had found the evidence which would **convict** Robert of murder.

> [**convict**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/convict)  - (vb tr/intr:)  *Law* - To find or prove (someone) guilty of an offense or crime, especially by the verdict of a court.
>
> - "The jury **convicted** the defendant of manslaughter."
> - "There is sufficient evidence to **convict** him."
> - "His son is in jail, **convicted** of drunk driving."
>
> [**convict**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convict) - (vb) to prove that someone is guilty of a crime in a court of law
>
> - "He was **convicted** in federal court."
> - "Have you ever been **convicted** of a crime?

**convict** is also a noun: [**a convict**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convict) is a person convicted of and under sentence for a crime.

Postscript - Yes, your first two sentences don't mean that Robert would be convicted in a court of law.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Judges and juries convict suspects. Evidence can only be said *to of had convicted / aided in conviction* -past tense.

Comment: *convict* is the right answer for the title question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree; you can be linked to a crime even if you're 100% innocent.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question doesn't match your context.

> Lucy realized she had the proof to _________ Robert.

The blank here is not a verb meaning "to prove his guilt".

> Lucy had proof to prove-the-guilt-of Robert.

That doesn't really make sense. A better way:

> Lucy realized she could prove Robert's guilt.

Alternately,

> Lucy realized she could secure Robert's conviction.

I would suggest:

> Lucy realized this was the smoking gun that would convict Robert.

This does several things. First, we're highlighting the now-valuable object in question. Second, we're using the cool phrase "smoking gun". Third, we're showing that the result of proof is a conviction. Fourth, we're acknowledging that the conviction is in the character's future still.

That phrase would need to be modified if the evidence is something she'd collected earlier and just now realized was evidence.

> Lucy realized the stray cat in her apartment was the smoking gun...

One last nitpick. "Realized she found" seems awkward to me. "Realized she'd found" seems more natural and accurate to me.

Comment: Great post .. You're saying "prove" is in fact the answer.

Comment: Which term would you prefer between *proof* and *evidence* and why?

Comment: I *do* like this answer...

Comment: *Evidence* is something that inclines you towards a conclusion, but doesn't get you the entire way. *Proof* is when you can't see anything but one conclusion as reasonable. To a court, the term *evidence* would make more sense, as they haven't yet determined guilt. If you asked them to examine the proof it would seem like guilt was pre-established. But to Lucy, guilt probably has been pre-determined, and this evidence is her means of proving it to a court. Because the sentence is about Lucy's thought process, it seems natural to use the term *proof* if that's how she views it.

Answer (score 2):

What about *prosecuted*? In the past tense the process has completed and a successful outcome would indicate proven.

Comment: This doesn't fit in with the story, Lucy doesn't know if the murderer will be put on trial. She has only discovered  the evidence and the motive that proves that Robert committed the two murders.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Culpable evidence that implicates guilt and motive legally proves nothing. *Innocent until **proven** guilty.* (If you include the word "*likely* to prove..." in the title, I'd leave you alone and tell you to go with *implicate* ;)

Comment: @Mazura It's the student's story, not mine :) We were both wondering if a verb existed that expressed the concept of finding the evidence that proves someone's guilt. The trial, which in any case is not mentioned in the story, is secondary. To reiterate, the proof and motive is damning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You sure you're not looking for an adjective to describe the proof and motive?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with some of your premises.

*Proof that frames* is an oxymoron, unless you qualify *proof* somehow to show it is not legitimate and doesn't actually prove guilt, as in *seeming proof that frames*. Consider other qualifiers such as *faked-up*, *false*, *circumstantial*, *misleading*, *misinterpreted*. (Note: *misinterpreted* was added in an edit, and at least one comment below refers to the post before this edit.)

Therefore, in my opinion, your sentences 1 and 2, "proof that nailed" or "proof that incriminated" are perfectly clear and acceptable. There is no other kind of (just plain) proof.

If you still have an issue with *proof* being ambiguous, then focus it with a qualifier: *the legitimate proof that incriminated*, for example, or try *iron-clad*, *solid*, *inescapable*, *ineluctable*, *absolute*, or *unquestionable*.

Comment: In the original sentence, my student used the term *frame*, I pointed out that it was incorrect because Robert *was* guilty of committing the murders. The term *frame* is normally used to trap  an innocent person. I'm pleased to hear that suggestions 1 and 2 are clear but I feel they are not wholly unambiguous. An innocent person can also be nailed or  incriminated for something they did not do.

Comment: @Mari-LouA For an innocent person, then there is no proof they committed the crime—at least, not *legitimate* proof. And, the word *proof* by itself should be understood to mean "legitimate proof". Therefore, sentences 1 and 2 are completely unambiguous. An innocent person can only be nailed or incriminated by misleading, false, trumped-up, faked, or otherwise invalid proof!

Comment: @ErikE You're forgetting a very common type: _misinterpreted_ proof; that is, something that is taken as proof, but is in fact not if you know the full context.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm not forgetting it at all because my analysis is not on the eventual disposition of an accused person within the court system, but on the meaning and ambiguity or clarity of particular sentences. Within the given sentences, the *misinterpreted proof* angle is not an issue. All proof, all statements, all claims and propositions, could be mistaken. if what you're saying really is an issue, then the current top answer, "proof that implicated" would also be completely ambiguous. No, words mean their usual/normal meaning in sentences until modifiers or context change them.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat old fashioned expression for this would be *bring home the crime to*. Your sentence would then read

> Lucy realized she had the proof to *bring home the crime to* Robert

Examples of this usage can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eight_of_Swords):-

> Mr. Depping turns out to have been an American criminal, and Gideon Fell must penetrate the secrets of his American associates as well as his British life in retirement in order to bring home the crime to the unlikely criminal.

or [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2GriAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT244&lpg=PT244&dq=%22bring%20home%20the%20crime%22&source=bl&ots=au81bgWeL-&sig=awyYoTFeLEyBp4f_Tqzu6xcBpeo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIz86uorzJxwIVgdsaCh3cFQVs#v=onepage&q=%22bring%20home%20the%20crime%22&f=false):-

> This seemed to bring home the crime now to Gaillard, and every effort
>   was made to discover him.

Answer (score 2):

As a lawyer, the sentence "Lucy realized she had the proof to *convict* Robert" has only 2 plausible meanings to me:

1. Lucy is the judge (or a member of the jury) trying Robert for the crime.
2. Lucy is the prosecutor or someone intimately involved in the prosecution, such as the investigating officer from the police.

The sentence would sound odd to me otherwise – including if Lucy were investigating in a private capacity (e.g. as an HR manager). In fact, even in sentence (2), I wouldn't choose to use the word 'convict' myself, but would instead prefer verbs like 'prove' or 'incriminate' ('smoking gun' would also work in a more colloquial setting, and I'm also partial to 'implicate' because lawyers are careful not to overstate the degree of certainty).

The reason is that in a legal context, 'to convict' is a verb intimately tied up with a verdict of guilt in a court. In that sense it is a step *beyond* proof that someone has committed a crime – for example, because we are often willing to accept a piece of evidence as 'proof' of something even if it would not suffice in court (either because that evidence is insufficiently probative or because it is improper in some way according to the rules of evidence), and also because a conviction is at the end of a process that begins as an exercise of discretion by the prosecutor (in common law countries like the US and England, that is) such that not all crimes are prosecuted in the first place.

(For the same reasons, I would not use the verb 'prosecute' unless Lucy is actually prosecuting Robert in court.)

Answer (score 1):

If proving Robert’s guilt would require a trial (and I think it would), perhaps you could come at this from a different angle and dance around this issue by instead saying:

> #3-Lucy realized she found the evidence which/that **[refuted
>   Robert’s {claim of} 
>   innocence](http://sports.yahoo.com/news/lance-armstrong-s-innocence-is-refuted-in-the-secret-race--but-many-may-not-care.html)**.

[Refute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refute): verb-/-to prove that (something) is not true. (Merriam-Webster)

**Irrefutable** could also work as an adjective to modify “evidence”:

> Lucy realized she found/had [the] irrefutable evidence of Robert’s
>   guilt.

[Irrefutable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/irrefutable): adjective-/- that cannot be refuted or disproved. (Dictionary Reference)

Answer (score 1):

Institutional context is important in the meaning of words. Since crime has a legal basis, only judicial institutions can decide what is or isn't *proof* of *guilt* in the violation of a statute. Morality aside, does committing a crime make you *guilty* of violating a statute, or does getting prosecuted? From a legal standpoint, the latter holds, as *guilt* is the decree of an institution. One cannot *prove* their own *innocence* anymore than they can *prove* the *guilt* of another. Hence, ***convict*** is the appropriate term here. Typically, only courts have the authority to use this term in the manner described. Otherwise, you would simply *implicate* them with *incriminating evidence*.

> [Convict](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/convict)
>
> *law : to prove that someone is guilty of a crime in a court of law*

Comment: This answer has already been suggested several times by [@Otheus](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/269394/44619), Centaurus, Kevin Workman, [MichaelS](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/269696/44619), and JesseM

Comment: True, but they fail to fully describe why institutional context is important in the meaning of words. If the question has already been adequately answered, it should be closed.

Comment: You don't close a question because it has received one or more answers! If that were the case than 70% of all questions on this site should be closed. There is no obligation on the OP (me) to accept one answer. I have, however, upvoted those answers which have been most helpful to me.

Comment: Yes, you do, when you have received the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

~~~
Lucy realized that she had the smoking gun that would nail Robert for the murders.

This conveys that Lucy had the evidence in hand, by whatever means she procured it, to convict Robert.

~~~
Lucy was responsible for finding the smoking gun that nailed Robert.

This identifies Lucy specifically as the 'finder' not creator of the evidence.

The examples I used also served tho clarify the timing off crime and conviction.  I hope this helps.

Comment: That's interesting, finding a smoking gun, doesn't exclude the possibility that a person could be falsely accused of murder. But in my student's story  Lucy did find the "smoking gun", alongside the realization that the murderer could finally be reported to the police.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the opposite of [exonerate](https://www.google.com/search?&q=define%3A+exonerate):

> (especially of an official body) absolve (someone) from blame for a fault or wrongdoing, especially after due consideration of the case.

And I found [these](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exonerate):

- blame
- condemn
- convict
- damn
- burden
- accuse
- incriminate

Comment: 'Blame', 'Damn', 'Burden', and 'Accuse' don't mean they are proven guilty.

Answer (score 0):

"Convict," "commit," or "prove" would all seem to be appropriate, depending on what you want to say.

"Convict" is right if you want to refer to him being found guilty in court (regardless of objective guilt, this is a finding of legal guilt).  He could be convicted if framed, really did it, or didn't.

"Commit" refers to if the person objectively did the crime or not. They either committed the act, or they didn't, regardless of if they get caught or not, found guilty or not.

"Prove" is all about belief.  It can prove guilt to an individual with no legal standing, or a jury, which would then result in a conviction.  In either case, the person may or may not have actually done the crime.

Faking evidence to "prove" guilt would be framing.

So it really depends on the precise meaning desired.  Legal, factual, or belief. Each could use different words for different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

When I really ponder over the sentence after picking my word, the sentence shrinks. My word is "Blameworthy" which means `responsible for wrongdoing` (and deserving of censure or blame).

The first sentence that I made from your given template was - "Lucy realized she could prove that Robert is *blameworthy*."

But even better sentence is

> Lucy realized Robert is blameworthy.

because the only way Lucy would have such a realization is when she has the proof and therefore *having proof* becomes implicit.