# What is a word for being jailed for something that you didn't do, or something that someone has framed you for?

Tags: single-word-requests

Just looking for a word that defines being jailed for something that you didn't do, or that someone framed you for.

Comment: sort of related: [A verb that means “to prove someone is guilty of a crime”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269306/a-verb-that-means-to-prove-someone-is-guilty-of-a-crime)

Comment: @JJJ Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). See also: [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 0):

Being detained wrongfully is "false imprisonment". Not sure if that meets your requirement of having to be framed.

Comment: False imprisonment could also be when others restrain someone's movement, according to Cornell Law: _"False imprisonment is an act punishable under criminal law as well as under tort law. Under tort law, it is classified as an intentional tort. A a person commits false imprisonment when he commits an act of restraint on another person which confines that person in a bounded area._ "[link](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/false_imprisonment). Also, being jailed implies that there has been some sort of trial (in most countries) (in which case I don't think there would be a false imprisonment)

Comment: @JJJ Yeah, I know it's a very broad term and probably not what the questioner needed. In my state it is/was the crime of kidnapping also.